# Add constraints to a UIButton class without creating new view or knowing specific parent view

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have a bunch of buttons in my app and I would like to use the same class for all of them (*UIButton*). I need to be able to change the constraints for all of them at the same time in the class, some of them will be nested in different parent-views. All of them were created in **Interface Builder** nested in their own *UIView* in a few horizontal and vertical *UIStackViews*.

Is this possible?

I was hoping to do something like this, but I don't know how to go further:

```
class myButtonClass: UIButton {

    required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder)!}
    
    override init(frame:CGRect) {super.init(frame: frame)
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    
    func setConstraints() {
       
        let topMarginConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: .self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.topMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation, toItem: .superview, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 2)
        
        //Additional Constraints
        
        self.addConstraints([topMarginConstraint])

    }
}
```

This doesn't work for a variety of reasons, some of the errors are because I don't know how to assign the above to an undisclosed superview(parent-view)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself by using .superview:

```
func setConstraints() {
    
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
    self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
    self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
```